# How is "on fleek" translated into Spanish?

Tags: traducción, coloquialismos, neologismos

**Primero mi pregunta en español:**

¿Cómo se traduce "on fleek" al español?

**Details in English:**

Social media, for various reasons, has given rise to lots of different slang words and expressions.
One that still continues to elude me when trying to explain these to native Spanish speakers is "on fleek". If profanity doesn't bother you, you can check out some of the definitions for it over at [**Urban Dictionary**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_Dictionary), which [says](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fleek):

> An annoying term used by annoying teenagers (see middleschoolers) meant to be "on point".

But something more useful might be the following article:

[**Geeking Out On "Fleek"**](https://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/dictionary/geeking-out-on-fleek/)

I also ran this through [**Power Thesaurus**](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/on_fleek), which gave me "classy" (*con clase*), "gorgeous" (*espléndido*), and "on trend" (*a la moda*?). I suppose, in a pinch, I could use one of those, but I was wondering if the hip Spanish speakers of today might be using something that captures the *bon mot*, portmanteau* quality of this neologism.

---

**This may be an urban myth, but a while back I read that the word "fleek" was a portmanteau of "flawless" and "unique."*

---

**Detalles en español:**

Las redes sociales, por diversas razones, han dado lugar a un montón de jerga.
La traducción que continúa eludiéndome cuando trato de explicar estas palabras a hablantes nativos de español, es "on fleek". Si la profanidad no te molesta, puedes mirar algunas de las definiciones para esta palabra en [**Urban Dictionary**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_Dictionary):

### [**on fleek**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fleek)

Pero algo más útil puede ser el artículo siguiente:

[**Geeking Out On "Fleek"**](https://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/dictionary/geeking-out-on-fleek/)

También busqué esta frase en [**Power Thesaurus**](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/on_fleek), que me dio "classy" (con clase), "gorgeous" (espléndido), y "on trend" (¿a la moda?). Supongo que, si no hubiera otro remedio, podría usar una de esas traducciones, pero me preguntaba si los muy ondas hispanohablantes de hoy podrían estar usando algo que capture los atributos de burla y palabra compuesta* de este neologismo.

---

**Lo que voy a escribir aquí podría ser un mito urbano, pero hace tiempo, leí que la palabra "fleek" es una palabra compuesta de "flawless" (sin defecto) y "unique" (singular).*

---

Como siempre, gracias de antemano por las sugerencias que puedas proveer.

Comment: Trick: get several synonyms in English, then look those up.  (This is a starting point.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que una expresión "moderna" que te puede servir, atendiendo a las primeras traducciones que aparecen en tu enlace, es:

> **[al pelo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SPSNBuG#7TiJ2tv)**.
>
> 2. loc. adv. coloq. A punto, con toda exactitud, a medida del deseo.

Usando un ejemplo parecido al de UrbanDictionary:

> —¡Hoy llevo las uñas al pelo!
>   — Uf, ¿a quién le importa?

En cuanto al aspecto de *portmanteau* que comentas, si no te importa usar palabras inventadas que no aparecen en el diccionario (como es el caso de *fleek*, de hecho, aunque [se están planteando incluirla](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/fleek-meaning-and-history)), podrías probar con ["**estupentástico**", "**fantabulosa**" y similares](http://diccionariolibre.com/hashtag/fantabuloso), aunque el sentido no sea exactamente el mismo. ¿Tal vez "**[perfectástica](https://www.google.es/search?q=perfect%C3%A1stica)**"?

Comment: ¿Qué tal *estupitástica?

Comment: @walen  Tu respuesta es perfectástica.  Gracias.